# BufferedReader pauses on .readLine() when using ProcessBuilder to execute simple Python script

Tags: java, python, netbeans, bufferedreader, processbuilder

I'm trying to use ProcessBuilder to execute a simple python script from CMD, which prints to the command line, then have that text read into Java and outputted through System.out.println() in netbeans. My issue is the BufferedReader seems to pause at .readLine() then output the text in bulk once the py script has stopped running, as opposed to outputting live.

My process is as follows:

[execute python script]

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(this::TEST);
```

[run execution]

```
public void TEST(){
    try {
        ProcessBuilder py = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/C", "C:\\Users\\Documents\\TEST.py");
        String readLine;
        Process launch = py.start();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(launch.getInputStream()));
        while((readLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(readLine);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {Logger.getLogger(Template.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}
}
```

[here is the python script i wish to run and read live]

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog, tkMessageBox


root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.resizable(width=Tkinter.TRUE, height=Tkinter.TRUE)
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(400,600))

print("hello1\n")
print("hello2\n")
print("hello3\n")
print("hello4\n")
print("hello5\n")
tkMessageBox.showinfo("Complete!", "testing")
print("hello6\n")
print("hello7\n")
print("hello8\n")
print("hello9\n")
print("hello10\n")
tkMessageBox.showinfo("Complete!", "testing")
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

First: Your command does not do anything. It is `cmd /C C:\Users\Documents\TEST.py` which does nothing but tell you that `C:\Users\Documents\TEST.py` is not a command. You would need to call `cmd /C start C:\Users\Documents\TEST.py` for it to do something.

Still this won't make your code work. The problem here is that you are invoking a cmd in there you start a python process. When you now grab the input stream you are getting the cmd input stream which is not the one you are looking for.

In order to get it to work invoke python directly by calling `python C:\Users\Documents\TEST.py`. Make sure python is in your `PATH` for this to work.

Your code should then look something like this:

```
try
{
    ProcessBuilder py = new ProcessBuilder("python", "C:\\Users\\Documents\\TEST.py");
    String readLine;
    Process launch = py.start();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(launch.getInputStream()));
    while ((readLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        System.out.println(readLine);
    }
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    Logger.getLogger(Template.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

This gives you exactly the result you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have python in PATH but when executing commands using ProcessBuilder, isn't the PATH variable not taken into consideration. Therefore I can only get it to work if I use the absolute path to python, which gives me the same issue. Any idea how I can get "python" to work?

Comment: If it is in your path it should work. Have you tried restarting your IDE/PC?

Comment: Okay, I've restarted my laptop and now "python" works just fine. But, for some reason my output is still in bulk after the script finishes.

Answer (score 0):

A common problem can be that you did not flush your python std out. I recommend adding

```py
import sys

# your code here...

sys.stdout.flush()
```

to your code to flush your python output.